# Matlab - define a general variable

Tags: matlab

I want to calculate Fourier series for some function `func`.

I build this method:

```
function y = CalcFourier(accurate, func, a, b, val_x) 
    f = @(x) eval(func);
    % calculate coefficients
    a0 = (2 / (b - a)) * calcArea(func, a , b);
    an = (2 / (b - a)) * calcArea(strcat(func, '*cos(2*n*pi*x / (b - a))'), a , b);
    an = (2 / (b - a)) * calcArea(strcat(func, '*sin(2*n*pi*x / (b - a))'), a , b);
    partial = 0;
    an_f = @(n) an;
    bn_f = @(n) bn;
    for n = 1:accurate
        partial = partial + an_f(n)* cos(2*n*pi*val_x / (b - a)) + bn_f(n) * sin(2*n*pi*val_x / (b - a));
    end

    y = (a0 / 2) + partial;
end
```

And this - to approximate the coefficient's:

```
function area = calcArea(func, a, b)
    f = @(x) eval(func);
    area = (a - b) * (f(a) - f(b)) / 2;
end
```

On line `an = (2 / (b - a)) * calcArea(strcat(func, '*cos(2*n*pi*x / (b - a))'), a , b);` I'm getting error:

```
??? Error using ==> eval
Undefined function or variable 'n'.

Error in ==> calcArea>@(x)eval(func) at 2
    f = @(x) eval(func);

Error in ==> calcArea at 3
    area = (a - b) * (f(a) - f(b)) / 2;

Error in ==> CalcFourier at 5
    an = (2 / (b - a)) * calcArea(strcat(func,
    '*cos(2*n*pi*x / (b - a))'), a , b);

>>
```

Is there any option to declate `n` as "some constant"? Thanks!

Comment: There are not constants in matlab. You can declare n as [global](http://www.mathworks.com.au/help/matlab/ref/global.html) though.

Answer (score 0):

You try to use a variable called `n` in line 4 of your code. However at that time `n` is not defined yet, that only happens in the for loop. (Tip: Use `dbstop if error` at all times, that way you can spot the problem more easily).

Though I don't fully grasp what you are doing I believe you need something like this:

`n=1` at the start of your CalcFourier function. Of course you can also choose to input n as a variable, or to move the corresponding line to a place where `n` is actually defined.

Furthermore you seem to use `n` in `calcArea`, but you don't try to pass it to the function at all.

---

All of this would be easier to find if you avoided the use of `eval`, perhaps you can try creating the function without it, and then matlab will more easily guide you to the problems in your code.

Answer (score 0):

if the symbolic toolbox is available it can be used to declare symbolic variables , which can be treated as 'some variable' and substituted with a value later.

however a few changes should be made for it to be implemented, generally converting anonymous functions to symbolic functions and any function of n to symbolic functions. And finally the answer produced will need to be converted from a symbolic value to some more easy to handle value e.g. double

quickly implementing this to your code as follows;

```
function y = test(accurate, func, a, b, val_x)
syms n x % declare symbolic variables
%f = symfun(eval(func),x); commented out as not used
```

The two lines above show the declaration of symbolic variables and the syntax for creating a symbolic function

```
% calculate coefficients
a0 = symfun((2 / (b - a)) * calcArea(func, a , b),x);
an = symfun((2 / (b - a)) * calcArea(strcat(func, '*cos(2*n*pi*x / (b - a))'),...
... a , b),[x n]);
bn = symfun((2 / (b - a)) * calcArea(strcat(func, '*sin(2*n*pi*x / (b - a))'),...
... a , b),[x n]);
partial = 0;
```

the function definitions in in your code are combined into the lines above, note they functions are of x and n, the substitution of x_val is done later here...

```
for n = 1:accurate
    partial = partial + an(val_x,n)* cos(2*n*pi*val_x / (b - a)) +...
    ... bn(val_x,n) * sin(2*n*pi*val_x / (b - a));
end
```

The for loop which now replaces the symbolic n with values and calls the symbolic functions with x_val and each n value

```
y = (a0 / 2) + partial;
y = double(y);
end
```

Finally the solution is calculated and then converted to double;

Disclaimer: I have not checked if this code generates the correct solution, however I hope it gives you enough information to understand what has been changed and why to carry out the process given in your code above, using the symbolic toolbox to address the issue...